# Invalid application ID with Facebook iOS application

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

Here is the error when I try to login from my app.

```
MyApp[47747:907] Failed to log in Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" 
UserInfo=0x1c5d3c50 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginCancelled, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 
"The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: Invalid application [My_App_Id]" 
UserInfo=0x1c5cb630 {NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: Invalid application [My_App_Id]}, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x1c584800, state: FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed, loginHandler: 0x0, appID: 589037374454169, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy: 0x1d0818a0>, expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>}
```

On another iPhone the authorization works without problems. I checked that on both devices, My App is enabled for Facebook native auth.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16):

Ok, my mistake. I was trying with my friend's Facebook account and he was not identified as a developer on Facebook.

Once I disabled the Sandbox mode for my app, login worked without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, as said above, you could disable the sandbox mode for your app, or you could add your friend as a developer on Facebook @developer.facebook.com (if you need).