# Facebook Sign In Error iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ipad, parse-platform

I developed iPhone app,

In which I have integrated SignIn with Facebook feature using Parse api.

I have logged in to the Facebook app through settings, When i was developing app at that time it was working properly but after my got live and i downloaded from store it is showing me this error:

[image]:
**Do i need to change anything, after my app got live in developer.Facebook.com ?**

Where i am doing mistake ? please help.

***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: Have you set permessions ? To be used than in that methods : openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've setup your App on Facebook correctly.

You need to set how your App integrates with Facebook to Native iOS App and enter the **Bundle ID** of your App into the designated field. (Edit: Note that bundle IDs are case sensitive)

[image]

Also make sure that you app is **not** in the development mode-

[image]

Comment: Yes i have set correctly: Bundle Id: `com.Appname-` and in status and review page i have tried with both `ON` and `OFF` but still doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you try with `SSO` On, and removing suffix? Also, I can see some alerts in your app settings, what's that?

Comment: did you enter correct App Id in parse.com Settings > user Authentication > Facebook  and also once cheek whether your application is in sandbox mode or not.

Comment: @SahilMittal you are talking about which alert ?

Comment: The "Alerts" tab just above the Localize and below the Open Graph in the App Settings side bar

Comment: yes it shows `Your app has been placed in development mode due to an invalid privacy policy. Please update your privacy policy listed for your app as the URL may be missing or returning an error.` where should i update privacy policy ?

Comment: @savana I have added `App Id` in parse but where to check `sandbox mode` in parse.com ?

Comment: @Krunal That means your app was in development mode, but you said its in live mode? Anyways, host a page on your server and provide privacy policy url in the app settings to avoid such thing. And savana is talking of the app sandbox mode that I've explained in the answer

Comment: yes my app is live, but i have added privacy policy url in `app detail section - Contact Info - privacy policy url` but still shows alert

Comment: Strange! All posts I found similar to this were due to development mode issue. [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085249/invalid-application-id-with-facebook-ios-application) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620317/ios-6-the-facebook-server-could-not-fulfill-this-access-request-invalid-applicat) ...

Comment: is there any solution for this ? I have added privacy policy but still shows error :(

Comment: in the application you are requesting to access user's email id from Facebook but in the Facebook permissions list you didn't include email , once check if all your permissions are right or not(I am saying this after checking app log after installation )